# Unable to bind the runtime of the zero reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting for yourself is not a known bug, this piece of code in another action normally works

```
Unable to bind the runtime of the zero reference
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Examine the stack trace for more information about this error and where it originated in the code.

  Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Unable to bind the runtime of the zero reference

Source Error:

Line 169:@for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
Line 170:{
Line 171:    <span>@Ajax.ActionLink((i * 5).ToString(), "Start", new { cost = (i * 5), gameId = Model.IdGame }, AjaxStart)</span> 
Line 172:}
Line 173:
```

> [RuntimeBinderException: Не удается выполнить привязки исполняющей
>   среды по нулевой ссылке]    CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite ,
>   Object ) +66
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0
>   arg0) +438    ASP._Page_Views_Kamikaze2_TestGamePlay_cshtml.Execute()
>   in c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Igrok56\Web\Views\Kamikaze2\TestGamePlay.cshtml:171
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +272
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +67
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +58
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +94
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +172
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +574
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +360
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +409    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19()
>   +60    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +391
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
>   +61    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +391
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1e.b*_1b()
>   +61    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +285
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +830
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +232    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +68
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *) +42    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +141    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +61
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +31
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
>   +56    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +110
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8967757    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs due to the fact that Model is null

Comment: OK, but what does "I'm getting for yourself is not a known bug" mean?